# Ho to store Admin users in Asp.Net Application with Asp.net Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.Net Application where I am using ASP.Net Membership Provider for authentication.Currently I am storing the admin users in the web.config file as a key value pair and getting that in my Asp.net application to check if user is admin or not and then showing them the pages based on that.

But the web.config values gets reset when customer install new version of application and they have to add the users manually again.

Is there any way I can store admin users details other than web.config?

Thanks in advance!

I was thinking to store Admin user in database but as we are using Asp.net membership provider we cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

Are not all other users in the database?

The fact that your using membership provider VERY much means you can store the admin user in the database. In fact, the admin user NOT out of the blue a admin user UNTILL such time you add a "role" to that user. So, you don't assume the user in the database is "admin", you add a role in the roles table called admin.

So, you going to have something like this:

[image]

So, then this:

```
 SELECT * from Web_Roles
```

| ID | RoleName | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Portal | Allows use of Portal |
| 2 | PortalMaster | Is a portal Master for a given Company |
| 4 | SiteAdmin | Site Administrator |
| 5 | Contractor | Contractor - allow multiple company use |
| 6 | Staff | Is Staff |

So, now you just make sure the user has a role called "SiteAdmin".

Now, you can secure ANY page, and ONLY users with role = admin can use that page. (and bonus points is ZERO code is required!!!!).

I mean, you can certainly in code behind test for role membership, say like this:

so say:

```
  If Roles.IsUserInRole("SiteAdmin") then

      ' do whatever based on role = siteAdmin

  End If
```

So, I don't see how or why you would suggest that you have some "admin" stored in a text file, or even in web config. That would NOT respect the security settings. If you secure a web page with a given role, then you don't need code to even check for such membership.

So, say we create a folder called SiteAdmin. Inside of that folder we would place/crate all the web pages for the site admin user.

The web config in that folder will then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>

    <authorization>
            <allow roles="SiteAdmin" />
        <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

</system.web>
</configuration>
```

So, only users in the Role SiteAdmin now can use that page.

Sometimes, we might use code behind and the above "role" check, to hide, or show things, but if you ARE REALLY using the membership provider, then simple add a user to the "users" table, and give that user membership in "siteAdmin" or whatever you wish to call it.

If you storing the user in some place else? Then how can you secure the "admin" pages in the application? I suppose you could write custom code behind, but the WHOLE point of such security is that you let IIS do all that stuff, and simple secure each page based on their role(s) they belong to. If you not doing that now, then I fail to see how you have actual security setup then?

So, it makes very little sense to have some user in say web.config, or even a text file, since that means the user will not be using the security system that you setup for the web site.

Where are all the other users being stored now?

Comment: Hi @Albert , Thanks for the detailed explanation. So , currently the users are stoired in the database table and we dont have any UI to update the table. I added a new column called IsAdmin to the users table and I could get this in my C# code to check if the user is admin then make the admin menu visible else hide it.The only odd thing here is we need to update the table by manual query to set IsAdmin for all the users who are admins.I have proposed a solution to add UI from where we can set this in future though.

Comment: Seems like you don't have a "roles" table for security? You secure web pages by "role" membership. (or at least you should be!). If using IIS security then it is simple to secure a web page by role membership, and do so without ANY code. It is thus (should be) the users "role" membership that allows and controls use of any web page.  You can add a column to the users table but IIS will not know what to do with that, and thus securing pages will not work based on role membership either.  To add roles to a given user, then you add a row to UserInRole table. Once done, all security is automatic.